# I have a layout I'm working on and I need help wrapping my head around where to get started

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a layout and instead of inserting an image, I wanted to try CSS. It seems like it's possible, but I don't know where to start. Everything is on a 20px grid, so what's the best way to line all of that up?

Here's a image to what I'm talking about.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: this look likes a tag clouds

Comment: I'm glad you said cloud because that's what I was going for!

Comment: Are the size, number and position of those boxes fixed or dynamic?

Comment: I'd like them to be dynamic by scaling them down slightly for a tablet and to have a kind of menu for a phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any grid systems available.
http://getbootstrap.com

Comment: I'll look into frameworks, I tried using Skeleton for something else and the site never look right.